# Mysql Foreign Key Creation

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to add foreign key to my table  with this script:

```
ALTER TABLE PRM_CTY
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PRM_CTY_PRNT_CTY
FOREIGN KEY (PRNT_CTY_ID)
REFERENCES PRM_CTY(ID);
```

this code work but foreign key doesnt creat. instead of this a new index is created named `fk_PRM_CTY_PRNT_CTY`.

my foreign key returns an index 
help me why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL automatically creates an index to support each foreign key constraint, unless a suitable one already exists.  The creation of an index suggests -- but does not prove -- that the constraint was successfully created.  It is *not* a sign that constraint creation failed.  To verify that the constraint exists, try to insert a row that violates it.

*Edited to add:*

Note, too, that you should be using the [InnoDB storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) if you want enforcement of foreign key constraints.  The default default was [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) prior to MySQL 5.5, and that engine is still available, so if you were not aware of this issue then that could be what you are using.

Comment: thank you for ypu answer. i triedt that but i can insert a row like that http://i.imgur.com/IG7m9kh.png

Comment: @spatialNinja My next best guess is that you are using a MySQL storage engine that does not enforce foreign key constraints.  I have updated my answer.